# iOS UIScrollView in UIWindow

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I currently am making an iOS project in which I have a `UIScrollView` as a direct subview of a `UIWindow` (using `[window addSubview:scrollView];`). The window's frame and its content are being set properly, and the `contentSize` is set to be bigger than the window's frame. When I try to scroll the UIScrollView, it doesn't scroll at all. Both `scrollEnabled` and `pagingEnabled` are set to `YES`, but the scrollview doesn't scroll, which leads me to believe that the touch/scroll events are not even being received by the scroll view. The window has a `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to it if it makes any difference. Do I need to somehow forward the swipe events to the `UIScrollView`, or is there a different reason that it's not scrolling?

EDIT: Here's some code.

```
   float count=ceil([self.msgArray count]/2); //msgArray has length of 3+, NSLog()'d and confirmed.
   float contentHeight=97.5 * count;
   [dataScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,contentHeight)];
   dataScrollView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   dataScrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
   dataScrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
   dataScrollView.clipsToBounds=YES; //Have also tried with this set to NO, or not set at all.
   //Add subviews to dataScrollView.
```

EDIT: Here's some more info.
contentHeight is 195.00 when logged. I've removed the delegate method and I am back to using direct subviews of the scroll view. The window's height is 97.50.

EDIT: I've also removed the UITapGestureRecognizer from the UIWindow, but the scrollview still doesn't scroll.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: become the thing's delegate and see if -scrollViewDidScroll is being called.  Or subclass it and override touch handling for a more concrete check

Comment: @lk.See edit. Added code.

Comment: Make sure you are implementing the [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) and returning the view you want to scroll from the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` method.

Comment: @ElliottPerry I just want it to scroll itself (scroll the contents). It has a bunch of UILabels as subviews, which I want to scroll.

Comment: @AehmloLxaitn Unfortunately that's not the way a `UIScrollView` works. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @ElliottPerry It's always worked for me in the past, without fail.

Comment: Can you log the contentHeight and see what its printing ?

Comment: @AehmloLxaitn Perhaps adding your content as direct subview of your `UIScrollView` does work but this is not the way it was intended for use as I understand it. In all of the Apple Developer sample code projects `UIScrollViews` are configured the way I describe in my answer. Either way, maybe it will solve your problem?

Comment: @ElliottPerry Didn't help.

Comment: So how would 195 be larger than the height of the window? I don't know of any iOS device that has a screen size of less than 195 points in any dimension (and it would be unusual to have a `UIWindow` that doesn't cover the entire screen).

Comment: @omz I'm unusual then. The window's height is 97.50.

Comment: So how do you add the window to the screen after all? It seems like there isn't enough code shown here to actually answer your question.

Comment: @omz It's a MobileSubstrate tweak which hooks into SpringBoard and initializes a custom subclass of `UIWindow`, sets the `windowLevel` to 1000 (`UIWindowLevelStatusBar`), and makes it the key window.

Comment: Oh, I see, that can't possibly have anything to do with the problem, good thing you didn't mention it.

Comment: @omz People tend to get freaked out about MobileSubstrate tweaks, so I try not to be obvious about it, even though it's the same as a normal app.

Comment: Is your scrollview the view of a view controller object? Is it a property of your application delegate? How are you getting/keeping references to it? Where is it being added in the application lifecycle -- are you just dropping a UIScrollView in the UIWindow in your app delegate?

Comment: @isaac It's not an app, it's a tweak hooking SpringBoard.

Comment: Your usage is pretty hazy as to where the scroll view resides within the responder chain (so in that sense, it really isn't like a 'normal' app). It's quite possible that your scrollview's gesture responders are conflicting with other gesture responders (eg, springboard's). You might need to set the delegate property for example shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the `UITapGestureRecognizer`! This might be a bug that took me hours to figure out in my own project. Is its `cancelsTouchesInView` property set to `NO` like it should be? (`YES` is the default... It can really throw you off if you're not expecting it.)

Comment: I set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO`, but it's still not scrolling.

Comment: Dang. I was sure that would be it.

Answer (score 0):

Just log the scrollview bounds width/height.  The content height you are setting should be greater than the scrollview height. If its more then the scroll view automatically enables its scrolling.

Comment: I did. The content height is greater, and the scroll view isn't scrolling.

Comment: your content height 195 is no way greater than the windows frame height. Wherever you are logging the content height ,log the scroll view height.

Comment: The scroll view's frame height is 97.5.